# Using wget and cron to download webpages

Tags: linux, cron, wget, tar

Ok, so I know i can use:

```
wget -r <website> > <file>
```

to get a webpage and save it. My question is, how would i use cron and wget to get a webpage on an hourly, or even minute basis, and then save them into a folder, zip and tarball it, and then keep adding to it for a review at a later date.

I know i can manually do this, my goal is to basically download it ever 10- 20 minutes, for roughly 4 hours (doesn't matter if it goes longer) and append the all into a nice directory, then zip said directory to conserve space, and check them later in the day.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what is your final result? First,  `-r` implies you want to save more then one page - is this what you want or not? If so, you should not say "webpage", but "web page**s**", just to be clear. I'll assume one page. So you download a page at, say, 10am, 11am and 12pm - what would you like to have - a set of files (`wp-10am.htm`, `wp-11am.htm`, `wp-12pm.htm`) or something else?

Comment: Something, i was mostly fiddleing around with wget for the first time, other than grabbing some quick files.

Comment: Mostly what i want to do, is to grab a webpage on a regular basis, and save it as index.<time>.htm in ~/web_logs/ which i'll then zip

Comment: victor hugo just answered the first part of that. The next part is to gz/zip it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit cron table

```
crontab -e
```

You can add an entry like this

```
0,20,40 * * * *  wget URL ~/files/file-`date > '+%m%d%y%H%M'`.html &
```

To download/save the file every 20 mins.

Here it is a [small reference](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) about crontab expressions so you can adjust the values

To TAR the files automatically the crontab would be slightly complex:

```
0,20,40 * * * *  wget URL > ~/files`date '+%m%d%y'`/file-`date '+%H%M'`.html &
* 12 * * *       tar cvf ~/archive-`date '+%m%d%y'`.tar ~/files`date '+%m%d%y'`
```

This would do it at noon, if you want to do it at mifnight it's more complex because you need to TAR the previous day but I think with this you'll get the idea.

Comment: Didn't notice before, but it's actually
    0,20,40 * * * *    wget URL > ~/files/file-`date '+%m%d%y%H%M'`.html &

Missed the >, was wondering why it wasn't working :P

Answer (score 1):

Or without cron:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do wget -r http://google.de -P $(date +%k_%M) && sleep 600; done
```

10 times, every 10 minutes

EDIT: Use zip like this

```
zip foo.zip file1 file2 allfile*.html
```